# Spring hibernate ManyToMany with extra fields

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm working on one demo project which has Driver and Licenses connected ManyToMany. Driver can have more licenses and one license can be connected to more drivers. This is not a driver licence. The license I am talking about is connected with the cargo that they can, or cannot transport. That is the way it should be.
Recently, I had one request to add two extra fields in this connection. Driver and License are connected ManyToMany by table Drivers_License. That extra filed goes to Drivers_License and that is expirationDate, and stateIssued.

This is the look of my database now.

```
Driver                          Driver_License                   License
-----------                     -------------------             --------------------
driverID                         driverID                         licenseID
driverName                       licenseID                        licenseName
driverNumber                     expirationDate    
driverDateOfBirth                stateIssued
```

The problem is that I need to break ManyToMany connection and create two OneToMany connections. I also need composite key to be made from driverID and licenseID.

This is the example of that I am talking about.
[Hibernate Many-to-Many Association with Extra Columns in Join Table Example](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-in-join-table-example)

Can you tell me if there is some complete example how to finish this using spring and hibernate, or maybe do you know some example that can handle this by using ManyToMany on a classical way?

Comment: Do you have control over the tables or is the schema generated from the Entities?

Comment: The schema is generated over the Entities.

Comment: Cool. Then why not just put the new two new fields in the License Entity?

Comment: So you mean that I can use ManyToMany and just put that fields in License instead of DriverLicense? Will try that. But then are there any changes in database?

Comment: Well, I don't see anything specifically that requires a ManyToMany. A OneToMany will do it. However lets be clear, I asked if the tables are being generated by your application or whether they are pre-existing? Or maybe you have a create script. At any rate, the new fields will go into the License table (and Entity).

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have managed to figure this out. I'm little new to all this. You have helped me to take a better look on situation in a project. There was also GSON error with internal loop that I managed to disable using transient. Thanks again.

Comment: When I finish this I will post my code.

Comment: It's good to be aware of what is being generated in the database, you will get a lot better a lot quicker that way.

Comment: Do you have any good example, that can be found on internet, and that has Entities, hibernate, spring and GUI? I was searching but there are a lot of examples without GUI. I think that my problems are connected with Entities.

Comment: You can try this [Spring Web JPA Starter](https://github.com/karlnicholas/springwebjpastarter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you are creating the schema yourself, you don't need to add the fields to the `join table`. Just add them to your license `Entity`. This would be an approximation of what you seem to be trying to do.

```
@Entity
public class Driver {    
    @Id @GeneratedValue private Integer id;
    @OneToMany private List<License> licenses;
    ... Driver Name, Number, & DateOfBirth ...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class License {    
    @Id @GeneratedValue private Integer id;
    private String licenseName;
    // add your fields here.
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date expirationDate;
    private String issueState;
}
```

Again, you don't want to mess with the `join table`, they are typically created automatically by the persistence provider.

The `licenses` list in the `Driver` table will refer to a `join table` that will hold many licenses for one driver, hence the `OneToMany` relation.

EDIT: If you have a specific license and want to find out which driver it belongs to, say because you have looked it up by its name, then you should add a reference back to the driver:

```
@ManyToOne
private Driver driver;
```

It will be a `ManyToOne` because you will have Many licenses which refer to One driver. This relationship will use the same `Join Table` that the `licenses` list in `Driver` uses. This will also create a circular reference, `Driver` refers to `License` and `License` refers to `Driver`. You will have to create the `Licenses` first, save them, create the `Driver`, add the licenses, save it, then `merge` the `Driver` into the `License`.

```
    for(License license: licenses) {
        em.persist(license);
    }
    Driver driver = new Driver();
    driver.getLicenses().add(licenses);
    em.persist(driver);
    // merge circular dependency
    for(License license: licenses) {
        license.setDriver(driver);
        em.merge(license);
    }
```

**GOOD ADVICE:** You should turn on the `SQL` output and play with the application a little bit to get a feel for what it can do and how it does it. Seeing everything in action will help you get a better feel about how this works. I usually make a simple web page with buttons such as create, print, delete and the like and watch the debug output.

Comment: Ok. This looks great. You have written Driver instead of License in second entity.

Comment: Is it then ok to have licenseID in Driver table, that can be serialized array of license id's? This is in case driver has more Licenses. These are licenses for cargo that he is driving with.

Comment: I just don't know how to organize database tables. i thought that expiration date and state issued should belong to Driver.

Comment: Ok, I think that I finally have complete picture. I will have entities as you posted here. in database I will have table Driver, and License that will have id, driverID, licenseName, expirationDate, stateIssued. I will have one more table to use just to keep 9 types of licenses that will be provided in view like form elements to select.

Comment: See my updates. Mostly, consider playing around with what you have at the moment to see how it works.

Comment: Can you give me some advice about this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35488933/spring-hibernate-manytomany-with-extra-fields
I have the same situation, but it seams that I have problem saving composite key and extra data into database, using hibernate. Maybe there is some example better organized then this.

Comment: I'm confused. That links back to this question.

Comment: Sorry this is the example here: http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-in-join-table-example

Comment: @MilanStrahinic it looks pretty straight forward. Post a new question here on SO if you have any troubles, otherwise I'm on linked-in.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Like I promised here is my solution. Nicolas helped me sole some problems in my Entity organization, and much more.

For my particular problem I have chosen this : http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-in-join-table-example

This solves work with hibernate. I have also used DTO to repack beans. This example here has one mistake, and that is that they are not using LAZY in composite ID creation. That is why this example has infinite loop problem.

Here is my code that solves this.

**Driver entity**

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "id.driver", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)

 private List<DriverLicense> driverLicense = new ArrayList<DriverLicense>();

 public List<DriverLicense> getDriverLicense() {
   return driverLicense;

 public void setDriverLicense(List<DriverLicense> driverLicense) {
   this.driverLicense = driverLicense;
 }
```

**DriverLicenseID (my composite key)**

```
@Embeddable
public class DriverLicenseID implements Serializable { 

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL) 
    @JoinColumn(name="driverID")
    private Driver driver;

    public Driver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    public void setDriver(Driver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private License license;

    public License getLicense() {
        return license;
    }

    public void setLicense(License license) {
        this.license = license;
    } 
}
```

**License entity**

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "id.license", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)

    private List<DriverLicense> driverLicense = new ArrayList<DriverLicense>();

    public List<DriverLicense> getDriverLicense() {
         return driverLicense;
    }

    public void setDriverLicense(List<DriverLicense> driverLicense) {
         this.driverLicense = driverLicense;
    }
```

Thank you Nick! You have helped me to understand concept of Entity, and much more. Style new to all this.