# Spring and Hibernate Many To Many with additional fields

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp, jstl

I have very interesting problem : [Spring hibernate ManyToMany with extra fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35488933/spring-hibernate-manytomany-with-extra-fields)

I suppose that this example works fine, but I cannot find DAO layer example with hibernate, and I have problem saving composite key into database. Maybe someone has complete example with minimal GUI in spring and JSP that can demonstrate this. Or maybe you have some better example.

Comment: This is the example I have used: http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-association-on-join-table-annotations-example

Answer (score 0):

Just let Hibernate help you handle it:

**Product.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Product")
public class Product {
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "products")
    @Cascade({ CascadeType.ALL })
    private Set<Offer> stores;
}
```

**Store.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Store")
public class Store {
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cascade({ CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(name = "store_product", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "storeId", updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "productId", updatable = false) })
    private Set<Product> products;
}
```

Now, you can add/edit/delete without worry about ManyToMany relationship

Comment: This is ok, but I wanted structure like this: http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-in-join-table-example

Comment: You can consider **Writing Tests** section as DAO